# editing a single element in text file in python

Tags: python

I have 500 *.txt files which are of the form given below

```
1 0.211648 0.496528 0.230114 0.159722
11 0.549716 0.232639 0.082386 0.145833
5 0.687500 0.539931 0.130682 0.128472
1 0.534091 0.809028 0.221591 0.194444
2 0.127841 0.637153 0.119318 0.128472
2 0.579545 0.482639 0.090909 0.069444
1 0.657670 0.269097 0.105114 0.121528
2 0.737216 0.348958 0.025568 0.086806
2 0.484375 0.302083 0.031250 0.069444
```

I need to replace '11' 1st number in the row with '10'
I have written following program for it but it doesn't work. can you please help.

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

os.chdir(r'../images')
myFiles = glob.glob('image*.txt')
import numpy as np
for i1 in myFiles:

  # print(i1)
  with open(i1, 'r') as f:
    # read a list of lines into data
    lines = f.readlines()

  r_id = np.arange(len(lines))
  for i in r_id:
      idx = list(map(float, lines[i].split(' ')))
      idx[0]=int(idx[0])
      if(idx[0]==11): 
        idx[0]=10
        with open(i1, 'w') as f:
          f.writelines(lines)

  f.close()
```

Comment: perhaps you meant ```myFiles = glob.glob('image\*.txt')```?

Comment: @Sujay I checked by printing the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use integers (10 and 11), but what you have there are strings.  You don't need numpy for this, it's a simple text substitution:

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir('../images')
myFiles = glob.glob('image*.txt')
for i1 in myFiles:
    lines = open(il,'r').readlines()
    with open(il,'w') as fout:
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('11 '):
                line = '10 '+line[3:]
            print( line, file=fout, end='' )
```

It could be even simpler if you wanted to write the result to a temp file and rename afterward.  Then you wouldn't need to read the whole file in.

Comment: your code creates spaces between lines, can you please tell me how to fix that

Comment: Honestly, you should have been able to figure that out.  It has spaces because "readlines" leaves the newline at the end, and `print` adds another.  So, you can either `.strip()` the newline, or tell `print` not to add one, which is what I did here.